# Learning PHP classes, variables vanish

Tags: php, class

I'm trying to teach myself how to use PHP's classes (I have a C# background) and I'm having difficulty understanding what I'm doing wrong.

I define a `book` class with various variables such as `author`, `isbn`, etc. I then create myself a `book` called `$book`, passing in values using a default constructor.

The problem is the last line:

`echo $book->name;`

I expected it to output "Perdido Street Station" but instead it outputs nothing.
What I have to do, it seems, is set the variable like so:

`$book->name = "Perdido Street Station";`

```
<?php
class book {
    var $name;
    var $isbn;
    var $author;
    var $publisher;
    var $publish_date;
    var $pages;

    function book($_name, $_isbn, $_author, $_publisher, $_publish_date, $_pages) {
        // type checking
        if (!is_string($_name) || !is_string($_isbn) || !is_string($_author) || !is_string($_publisher) || !is_string($_publish_date) || !is_int($_pages)) {
            return false;
        }
        $name         = $_name;
        $isbn         = $_isbn;
        $author       = $_author;
        $publisher    = $_publisher;
        $publish_date = $_publish_date;
        $pages        = $_pages;
    }
}

$book = new book("Perdido Street Station", "0330534238", "China Miéville", "Pan", "2011-05-2011", 867);
echo $book->name;
?>
```

There must be something obvious that I'm doing wrong here. Any help?

Comment: Whatever documentation or tutorial you are following to learn PHP's class definition syntax, you should abandon it in favor of an up to date one. The `var $property` syntax is PHP 4 style, and deprecated. [Here is the official PHP documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to use `$this->` to assign to the variables of the class:

```
$this->name         = $_name;
$this->isbn         = $_isbn;
$this->author       = $_author;
$this->publisher    = $_publisher
$this->publish_date = $_publish_date;
$this->pages        = $_pages;
```

Answer (score 4):

Constructors in PHP have a different syntax than the one you are using:

```
class SomeClass {
   function __construct() {
       // Assign variables here
   }
}
```

Comment: Just noting that the OP's code will work in this instance because the OP is using the old style constructor (although not recommended). From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php): For backwards compatibility, if PHP 5 cannot find a __construct() function for a given class, and the class did not inherit one from a parent class, it will search for the old-style constructor function, by the name of the class.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, this was one point I wasn't sure on. PHP is a funny guy, eh.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not entirely sure about this, but it may be that you must use the `$this` variable inside your class to set member variables in your class.  I think what you are doing currently, is creating temporary variables that are only inside your function.